# Optimizing specific sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am not an SQL expert, please help, how can I optimize this query?

I don't have indexes, only the table called master_table and more tables, I must optimize this query to get the same results, I can create indexes if I have to, but I cannot change the creation table....

```
select month(date_hour), passenger, nationality, passport, airline,
   count(*) N_Viagens
from masterTable
group by month(date_hour), passenger, airline, nationality, passport 
having count(*) > 10
```

next is the code to create the table but I can't edit that code, only the query or creating indexes:

```
select
p.birthdate, p.gender, p.passport, p.name + ' ' + p.surname passenger, p.nationality,
    r.class, r.flightNR, r.payment, r.ticketNR,
    f.src_AP_ID, f.dest_AP_ID, f.AL_ID, f.date_hour, f.AirCrft_Code,ac.manufacturer, ac.model,
    SA.City 'Origin City', SA.Country 'Origin Country', SA.Name 'Origin Airport', 
    DA.City 'Dest City', DA.Country 'Dest Country', DA.Name 'Dest Airport',
    al.Name airline, al.IATA, al.icao
into masterTable 
from passenger p
join reservation r on r.passport = p.passport
join flight f on f.flightNR = r.flightNR
join airport SA on f.src_AP_ID = SA.AP_Id 
join airport DA on f.dest_AP_ID = DA.AP_Id 
join aircraft ac on f.airCrft_Code = ac.code
join airline al on f.AL_ID = al.AL_ID
```

without index:

```
SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 10125 ms,  elapsed time = 17052 ms.
```

PEOPLE I THINK I DID IT, THANKS TO ALL OF YOU, THANK YOU AGAIN

I created the index like this:

```
create index idx_MasterTable_Passenger on masterTable(passport, airline)
```

and the query I changed to this:

```
select month(date_hour), max(passenger) as passenger, nationality, passport, airline, count(*) N_Viagens
from masterTable
group by airline, nationality, passport, month(date_hour)
having count(*) > 10
```

What you think, is it acceptable?

```
SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 8362 ms,  elapsed time = 5721 ms.
```

I will talk to the teacher if he agrees with this

**The teacher did not accepted this changes, we cannot change tables or query, only creating a good index.... suggestions??**

Comment: `GROUP BY month(date_hour)`? So you don't care if the count comes from November 2000 or November 2011 or any other year, just throw them all in the same bucket?

Comment: And adding an index on Natural Key(passenger, airline, nationality) would definitely speed things up. It will make inserts slower, but selects faster

Comment: This was given by my professor just like it is, my work is to turn it fast

Comment: @MikeTWebb, like this?

`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index1 ON masterTable 
    (
        passenger ASC,
        nationality ASC,
        airline ASC
    )WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO`

Comment: @Chris Shain , sry, i am still learning how to use this website, thank you =)

Comment: @DaniSilva no problem.  It would be helpful to see the query plan for this.  Look up how to get a query plan, then edit your post and add a screenshot of the plan.

Comment: @Dani....yep. That should do it.  Let me know if that helps and I'll post it in an answer :)

Comment: Based query to produce masterTable I don't agree with the query.  It appears passport is the PK.  Can have two different people with the same name.  Passport is a better identified and also a more efficient index as it is smaller.

Comment: @Blam....agreed. would be worth a try.  I didn't notice passport was the PK

Comment: What was the actual question your professor asked? The query you came up with first does not necessarily answer that question.

Comment: I have that query i posted in the beginning of this page, it was given by the teacher, the scripts to create the table was also given by the teacher, my work is to speed that query, changing it (but not change results) or creating indexes, i sent him an e-mail asking what can i use

Comment: Then I would answer the stated question and for extra credit suggest the stated question is flawed.  The query does not account for year.  If a user changes names then their flights are split.

Comment: I don't suppose that Elbonia and Croutonistan would both issue Passport #42.  Additional extra credit for pointing out that both Nationality and Passport should be used together to uniquely identify the bearer.

Comment: @user92546 I agree.  I looked at my US passport and it is just a number

Comment: Please see what i did to my work, Agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears passport is a better identifier than name.  Allow for the fact person many have changed their name.

Create an index on  passport, airline

You could extend the index to nationality, passport, airline, passenger  but not sure how much that you buy you?

```
select nationality, passport, airline, year(date_hour), month(date_hour), max(passenger), count(*) N_Viagens
from masterTable 
group by  nationality, passport, airline, year(date_hour), month(date_hour) 
having count(*) > 10
```

Comment: WAIT.... i did this and SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 9595 ms,  elapsed time = 6490 ms.... and it shows the 30949 results..... hummm but i think

Comment: heheheh i did it, its a kind of stupid lol but it works, i edited the query that i had to this:
`select month(date_hour), max(passenger), nationality, passport, airline, count(*) N_Viagens
from masterTable
group by airline, nationality, passport, month(date_hour)
having count(*) > 10`
and the times:
` SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 8315 ms,  elapsed time = 5765 ms.`

Comment: sorry, i was doing that now, im new here, i registered today, sorry, but you are right about the year, makes no sense

Comment: i cannot vote up, it says that requires 15 reputation :S what can i do?

Comment: is it possible to add the users as friends here?? (sry the noob question)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.   You can favorite a question.  Then from the question you can drill to the user.

Comment: Click the Star on the question.  Then it will be saved in you Favorites.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one - to really speed up the grouping on `month(date_hour)`, you'll need a **functional index** (a.k.a. [index on a computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx) in MS SQL Server) on that exact expression. Just having an index on `date_hour` isn't enough.

In [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e52c/3), the second table has a computed column and an index on it (while the first one has neither). Note how identical queries have different execution plans where the first one actually sorts the data and the second one just whizzes through the index.

Since this is a homework, I'll let you incorporate this yourself into your example.

BTW, if you are interested in the topic of indexes and performance, I warmly recommend reading: [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)

Comment: This is the best approach if performance is what matters. The index should be on all 5 columns (4 "usual" and 1 computed): `(the_month, passenger, airline, nationality, passport)`

Comment: i can't change the tables that are created, my teacher said i must keep the query and tables, only acelerate, so i think i need only a good index or external auxiliar tables if needed

Comment: @DaniSilva Well, that depends on how you define "changing the table". By creating a computed column, you are not changing the physical table data in any way. In this context, computed column is simply a supporting mechanism for indexing.

Comment: that is to much to me :P i saw the example and i saw the "create table" queries, so i thought i had to change the tables that i had already created

Comment: but i want to try this as well!

Comment: @Branko I suspect not being allowed to "change the table" means CREATE INDEX is ok, but ALTER TABLE is not (even if said ALTER does not fundamentally change the underlying table). Once you index it, of course, it's hard to say you haven't changed the table, since this behaves almost identically to a persisted computed column (not according to the query plan, but according to DBCC IND/DBCC PAGE).

Comment: @AaronBertrand There are DBMSes under which you can do almost exactly the same thing without ALTER TABLE. Using ALTER TABLE is incidental (an artifact of particular DBMS' syntax), not essential.

Comment: @Branko yes, I understand, but in SQL Server you can only add a column using ALTER TABLE, and that might be how the OP defines "changing the table." I'd argue that it is quite subjective to suggest that adding a computed column isn't "changing the table" regardless of your specific definition or your RDBMS, but particularly in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

What does MasterTable contain?  It seems like it would contain something like flight segments for passengers.  If so, very few passengers fly more than 10 times in a month.

You might be able to improve the performance by doing the following:

(1) Build an index on passenger in the MasterTable:

```
create index idx_MasterTable_Passenger on MasterTable(Passenger);
```

(2) Recognize that people who fly 10 times are rare relative to everyone else, so filter them out:

```
select month(date_hour), passenger, nationality, passport, airline,
       count(*) as N_Viagens
from masterTable
where passenger in (select passenger from MasterTable group by passenger having count(*) >= 10)
group by month(date_hour), passenger, airline, nationality, passport
having count(*) > 10
```

This might speed up the query.

However, I would suggest something a bit different.  Create a table that summarizes information by passenger (or some similar level) to answer questions such as this.  When new data is added to the main table, update or insert rows into this table.

For instance, you might want a summary table with a structure of , , .  Run this query once at night or once a week, and it could possibly answer many questions.

Comment: SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 11560 ms,  elapsed time = 18903 ms.
It gives me more time, it's strange
Am i doing something wrong?
I run the first query to create the index, then i run the second query as it is here, copy+paste, and the time is bigger :S

Comment: I disagree with people that have flown 10 times on any airline across all months is rare.  Most please that have flow have flown 10 times in their life.  10 times in a single month on a single airline is WAY different than 10 times ever.

Answer (score 0):

This query will always require a scan. There is now WHERE clause so we can't speed up the query by quickly isolating a smaller subset. There is a HAVING clause but it can be applied only after aggregation.

There is however a GROUP BY clause; aggregation on the GROUP BY clause could be sped up by adding an appropriate index. Because columns from the GROUP BY clause are also used in the SELECT list, we can achieve that only that index needs to be scanned, not the entire table.

The GROUP BY clause contains the expression month(date_hour). It means we can disregard this for the index. Remains passenger, airline, nationality, passport. You have to figure out the correct order before you create an index. My hunch is that you need to put the most selective columns first - that is, the columns with the most number of unique values should appear before those that have a low number of unique values. I would guess that the order passenger, airline, nationality, passport is already pretty good. That said I would experiment a little by changing the order of the columns.

Once you created the index, you'll shouldnt have to rewrite the query. However, if the optimizer of your RDBMS is naive (like MySQL's) you'd have to put the month(date_hour) expression as last expression of the GROUP BY clause. This won't change the result in any way although it may affect the order in whic the rows are returned. However that shouldn't matter at all (and if it does, you should've added a ORDER BY clause)

Comment: _"... expression month(date_hour). It means we can disregard this for the index."_ Unless the DBMS supports functional indexes, which MS SQL does. Also, the order in GROUP BY matters. While putting `month(date_hour)` at the end would help performance (in the absence of appropriate functional index), it would also change the meaning of the query. The OP will have to decide if this change would be acceptable.

Comment: "Also, the order in GROUP BY matters." < it does not." it would also change the meaning of the query." < no. Grouping by means aggregating on a list of expressions so that the resulting table has exactly one row for each combination of the GROUP BY columns. The order of the columns does exactly nothing to change the number and types of combinations.

Comment: You are correct. I think there might be differences for ROLLUP and such, but this doesn't matter in this particular case.

Comment: Branko, you're correct too w/re the functional indexes. Gap in my knowledge. I thought a bit about ROLLUP...since it generates supperaggregate rows in order of the GROUP BY columns, then yes, the result would in that case be very different.

Comment: SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 9625 ms,  elapsed time = 17400 ms.
After changing the order (put month in the end) of the group by clause.
The times are very equal with the solutions i tested

Comment: yea, I think it's smart enough to not care about group by column order.